# Import data using data entities in d365

Tags: import, data-entities

Why data is not getting updated in the table while importing using data entities in d365?

I tried importing data from excel to a table (employee table which I created in visual studio and created data entity on it), but the data can be seen in staging table but not in the employee table while viewing through table browser.